# Vue.js mixin introduce local state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have Vue mixin which looks like this:

```
/* eslint-disable */
const amount = null;
const currency = '';

export default {
    methods: {
        formatPrice(amount, currency) {
            this.amount = amount;
            this.currency = currency;

            const isInt = Number.isInteger(this.amountToPrice);

            return isInt ? this.stripDecimalZeroes : this.localePrice;
        }
    }
}
```

I have introduced a bit of local state by putting 2 variables inside of this file but ESLint is giving me a "no-shadow" error if I remove my `eslint-disable`.

What can I do to properly introduce a local state inside my mixin though. I do not want to pass around the state to every function and I don't feel like I am obligated to do so when the logic is encapsulated inside this mixin.

Also I do not understand the `no-shadow-error` when I am referencing my local state amount as `this.state` and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you could assign your variable to `this` in the `created () {}` hook, as follows:

```
created() {
    this.amount = null;
    this.currency = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by simplying doing the following:

Introduced state:

```
const state = {
    amount: null,
    currency: ''
};
```

Called the state like so:

```
export default {
    methods: {
        formatPrice(amount, currency) {
            state.amount = amount;
            state.currency = currency;
```